# Understanding when certain components need a lower voltage

Tags: voltage, current

When looking at electronic modules to buy (WiFi, sound etc) many descriptions say that the module cannot use a 5V input. But the 5V supply can be used if it's stepped down to 3.3V (or whatever is needed).

What I don't understand is that when I create a series circuit with a 9V battery and some LEDs that have a drop of 2V I don't need to step down the battery to 2V, the LEDs use only what voltage they need.

So why don't modules just take only the voltage they need? Why does the input need to be explicitly reduced?

Comment: So - what else do you have in your example series circuit? I'll bet its not just the 2 LEDs with a 9V battery (not for long before the smoke comes out anyway).

Comment: *I don't need to step down the battery to 2V* well, you kind of do, that's what the resistor is for. But start with the basics: do you understand what voltage is?

Comment: I would include a resistor in the LED circuit but that limits current and doesn't step down voltage?

Comment: Build the LED circuit and measure the voltage across the resistor and across the LED.

Comment: the resistor limits current by reducing the available voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For diodes:**

If you apply too high of a voltage to a diode, it will conduct lots of current and burn itself out very quickly.  If you apply too low a voltage to a diode, it won't turn on.  The solution is to apply exactly 2 volts to the diode.  With one diode and a 9 volt battery, the simple solution is to put a resistor in series with the diode to burn off 7 volts of the energy so the diode only sees 2 volts.  Note that this creates a DC current through the diode and resistor.

Remember, diodes have a constant voltage drop, not a constant current.  The diode will pull whatever current is necessary to have only 2 volts drop across its PN junction.  If a current limiting resistor isn't used, then the diode will be using the resistance of the copper as the current limiting resistor and will pull enough current to cause a 7 volt drop across the resistance in the copper.  This is assuming ideal diodes that never burn out.  A real diode would burn up quickly.

**For integrated circuits (ICs):**

The problem with "electronic modules" (or ICs) is that the amount of current needed varies with time.  For example, a microcontroller has many, many diodes in it.  Sometimes, parts of the IC (like the ADC) are turned off and those diodes are not conducting very much current.  Later, that part of the chip might be turned on and now all the extra diodes (for the ADC) require additional current to function.  What this means, is the current flowing into an IC is often AC current.

The problem is that AC current through a current limiting resistor creates AC voltage.  If the AC voltage drops below the threshold voltage of the diodes, then the chip stops working because all the diodes are off.  If the voltage rises too high, then the chip will conduct lots of current and burn itself out just like a diode without a current limiting resistor.  What the IC needs is DC voltage that isn't too low or too high.  The simple solution is to apply exactly 2 volts.  The problem is you only have a 9 volt battery.  There are a few solutions.  Voltage regulators basically create AC resistance that compensates for the AC current to create a DC voltage output.  So, it provides a current limiting resistor to burn off the extra 7 volts, but it changes it resistance to allow the correct current into the IC.  Buck regulators step the voltage down by quickly connecting and disconnecting the power and using a capacitor to smooth the voltage to a near constant 2 volts.  So the buck regulator would be connected approximately 2/9 of the time, and disconnected approximately 7/9 of the time.

I oversimplified some things, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Graph showing relationship between current through LED as a function of the applied voltage. Image source: [Check Study](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/given-blue-led-45v-battery-want-make-led-light-need-10-ma-current--build-circuit-left-sele-q5451038).*

> So why don't modules just take only the voltage they need?

Have a look at the curve for a green LED in Figure 1. A typical small LED is designed to run at 10 to 20 mA. The graph shows that 10 mA (0.01 A) will flow when there is 2.2 V across the LED. The converse is also true: if you apply 2.2 V across the green LED then about 10 mA will flow (but see note below).

Now consider what the current through the LED will be if you increase the voltage to 2.5 V: it will be about 40 mA and you will be exceeding the maximum current of the LED. Increase to 3 V and we're off the scale. At 9 V it's going to be many amps and the life of the LED will be microseconds. You might see it blink.

Note: because the current curve is so steep we don't control LEDs by setting the voltage. A small deviation in voltage or deviation between LEDs would cause a large deviation in current. Instead we control the current through the LED - typically by addition of a series resistor.

Comment: I think I've worded my question poorly or misunderstood your answer. If I use an arduino to supply 5V to a WiFi module that uses 3.3V, why do I need to step down the arduino voltage to 3.3V? Why doesn't the WiFi module just use 3.3V out of the 5V being input to it? I'm very new to electronics so please forgive my poor understanding

Comment: The 3.3 V circuit will be electrically stressed beyond it's maximum. The 5 V supply will damage the internal components. Even if the device was a simple resistor the current would be higher than it should: from Ohm's law \$ I = \frac {V}{R} \$ so if we increase V by 50% then I will increase by the same amount. Integrated circuits with their transistors may behave more like the diode curves and disproportionally higher currents may flow.